# OpenNI with ROS

Tags: ros, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have the OpenNI files of Occipital and have installed it
How do I enable the ROS to launch th sensor

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175183/openni-with-ros/) by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-08-13**:
I am using structure sensor called Occipital which supports OpenNI 2.0
From where can I download the openni file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about your specific setup, but there is a package that handles launching the OpenNi node:
http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch

Maybe this could help you

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0